# How to handle changed items with ListAdapter and DiffUtil?

Tags: android, listadapter, android-diffutils

I am facing an issue where a change in an item is not reflected when using submitList in ListAdapter.

I know that below code works in case I want to remove an item when using ListAdapter as inside submitList the framework checks whether lists are similar. It is also demonstrated in this sample from one of the developers working at Google
https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/RecyclerViewKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/recyclersample/data/DataSource.kt

```kotlin
fun removeItem(position: Int)
{
  val copiedList = adapter.currentList.toMutableList()
  copiedList.removeAt(position)
  adapter.submitList(copiedList)
}
```

The problem is when you want to change something using same method it won't work because toMutableList() creates a shallow copy of the list.

and thus when I do this,

```kotlin
fun changeItemAtPositionWith(isEnabled: Boolean, position: Int) {
  val copiedList = adapter.currentList.toMutableList()
  copiedList[position].isEnabled = !copiedList[position].isEnabled
  adapter.submitList(copiedList)
}
```

It doesn't work because content of both lists (copied and non-copied) refer to the same items and while comparing ListAdapter doesn't find any change.

I don't think creating deep copy for every change is a good idea at all.

Comment: Can you share your isContentTheSame and areItemsTheSame functions?

Comment: areItemsTheSame returns olditem.id == newItem.id

isContentTheSame returns olditem == new item

I am using a data class

Comment: Ok and is isEnabled part of your data class constructor? What I am guessing is isEnabled is not part of your equals function hence isContentTheSame is returning true even when you are changing the isEnabled flag. Can you post your data class as well please

Comment: Did you use `ViewModel` or `LiveData` or `StateFlow` in your project?

Comment: I have used ViewModel and Live data, But I think this question is independent of it. You can see the smallest reporducible scenario is to just use a list, adapter, diffutil.itemcallback and recycler view

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could solve it was to copy the object which has to be updated as shown below:

```kotlin
fun updateItemAtPosition(cheeseType, position) {
   val newPizza = pizzas[position].copy(cheese = cheeseType)
   pizzas[position] = newPizza
   adapter.submitAndUpdateList(pizzas)
}
```

And here is what submitAndUpdateList does

```kotlin
fun submitAndUpdateList(list: List<Pizza>) {
   submitList(list.toMutableList())
}
```

Here is the link to GitHub project, you can try running the app
https://github.com/ndhabrde11/ListAdapter-Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/listadaptertest/PizzaAdapter.kt